# request signature does not match with the provided signature in execute-api service of AWS

Tags: apex, rest-api, integration, amazon-aws

```
String dateStamp = EncodingUtil.urlEncode( System.now().formatGmt('yyyyMMdd'), 'UTF-8');
System.debug('dateStamp>>' + dateStamp);
String dateTimeStamp = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(System.now().formatGmt('yyyyMMdd') + 'T' + System.now().formatGmt('HHmmss') + 'Z', 'UTF-8');
System.debug('dateTimeStamp>>' + dateTimeStamp);

String url = 'https://awis.api.alexa.com/api?';

String algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256';
String credentialScope = dateStamp + '/us-east-1/execute-api/aws4_request';
String canonicalQuery = 'Action=UrlInfo&ResponseGroup=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode('Rank', 'UTF-8') 
                                + '&Url=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(urlToQuery, 'UTF-8') ;

String canonicalHeaders = 'host:awis.api.alexa.com\nx-amz-date:' + dateTimeStamp; 
String signedHeaders = 'host;x-amz-date';

String payloadHash = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(Crypto.generateDigest('sha256', Blob.valueOf('')));

String canonicalRequest = 'GET\n' + '/api' + '\n' + canonicalQuery + '\n' + canonicalHeaders  +'\n' + signedHeaders + '\n' + payloadHash;
//EncodingUtil.converttohex
String stringToSign = algorithm + '\n' +  dateTimeStamp + '\n' +  credentialScope + '\n' +  EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Crypto.generateDigest('sha256',Blob.valueOf(canonicalRequest)));



Blob signingKey = Crypto.generateMac('hmacSHA256', Blob.valueOf('aws4_request'),
    Crypto.generateMac('hmacSHA256', Blob.valueOf('execute-api'),
        Crypto.generateMac('hmacSHA256', Blob.valueOf('us-east-1'),
            Crypto.generateMac('hmacSHA256', Blob.valueOf(dateStamp), Blob.valueOf('AWS4' + alexaSettings.SecretAccessKey__c))
        )
    )
);
//EncodingUtil.convertToHex(
String signature = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(Crypto.generateMac('hmacSHA256', Blob.valueOf(stringToSign), signingKey));
System.debug('signature:::' + signature);

String authorizationHeader = algorithm + ' ' + 'Credential=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(alexaSettings.AWSAccessKeyId__c, 'UTF-8') + '/' + credentialScope + ', ' +  'SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date, ' + 'Signature=' + signature;

url = url + canonicalQuery;

System.debug('The URL is: ' + url);

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
Http http = new Http();
req.setEndpoint(url);
req.setHeader('Accept','application/xml');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');

req.setHeader('X-Amz-Date', dateTimeStamp);


req.setHeader('Authorization',authorizationHeader);

req.setMethod('GET');
req.setTimeout(10000);                                   
res = http.send(req);
```

I am trying to get website rank using Alexa Web Information Service. But I am getting this error -

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
>   provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult
>   the service documentation for details.

Can anybody help me in knowing the flaws I'm having inside my code.

Comment: The error message seems remarkably clear here. You should take the advice in the error message and consult the AWIS documentation.

Comment: @DerekF I went thru with documentation and checked the steps to create signature, but that was not helpful to me.

Comment: If you wait a few weeks for Summer '19 to hit, you can have AWS signature V4 support out of the box via Named Credentials: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_security_more_auth_protocols.htm